# How to pass ref to component optionally in React Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ref

```
const TitledContentCard = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {

  const { classes, title, actions, anchor, sectionId } = props;

  return (
    <div className={classes.card} id={sectionId} key={anchor} ref={ref}>
      <div className={classes.cardHeader}>
        <Typography className={classes.sectionTitle} variant="h3">{title}</Typography>
        <div className={classes.cardActions}>
          {actions}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
});
```

In the above code, I want to pass `ref` only when `ref` is not `undefined`
The above code return error when `ref` is `undefined`.

Comment: What error does it give you? It could be that the error is occurring elsewhere. This code snippet, as it is, looks fine to me.

Comment: Even if ref is `undefined` you won't get an error, the error comes from other source, you should make a reproducible example.

Comment: This is the error.

Warning: [object Object]: `ref` is not a prop. Trying to access it will result in `undefined` being returned. If you need to access the same value within the child component, you should pass it as a different prop.

Comment: Please show all related working code. You can re-create the error on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla-react-template-irhcq)